# Get value from select statement in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
   $user_id = 1; 
   $sq = "SELECT last_sess_id from user_login WHERE user_id = ?"; 
    $q = $this->db->query($sq, array($user_id));
    if($q->num_rows() > 0)
       { 
          foreach($q->result() as $result)
              {
                 $result->last_sess_id;    
              }
        }        

    $user_password_encrypt= sha1($last_sess_id."shelfbudencryption".$user_login_pass.$user_login_email);
```

How do i get the last_sess_id value from the select statement

Please help?

Comment: How could `$user_id` defined?

Comment: @vini show the table definition of `user_login `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, **`$q->result()`** will return a set of results, intead of that, you need to get a row. So, use **`$q->row()`**

```
$sq = "SELECT last_sess_id from user_login WHERE user_id = ?"; 
$q = $this->db->query($sq, array($user_id));
if($q->num_rows() > 0)
{ 
    $result = $q->row();
    $user_password_encrypt=sha1($result['last_sess_id']."shelfbudencryption".$user_login_pass.$user_login_email);
}
```

Hope this helps :)